# How NOT to pass click event to the children in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, dom-events

I use `material-ui`.

In this code https://codesandbox.io/s/y4jwv4ry1

1. I have one parent component `SimplePopper` which renders Toggle `Button` and which is wrapped inside a `Popper`.
2. Root `div` of `SimplePopper` is clickable (I can't transfer this click event to `Botton` coz in the actual code which I am writing I am not supposed to modify the existing code)
3. Coming to the application level:

   a. I have a Toggle button, if I click on it I get log 'parent Button'.

   b. If I hover on the Toggle button I get Popper.
4. Since I have onClick is already on the root of the parent`SimplePopper`, if I click anywhere inside the Popper, it will trigger the parent click event. **How to prevent triggering any event present in the Parent by clicking on the children?**

Please check out the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/y4jwv4ry1

Comment: Can't you just `e.stopPropagation` on the event?

Comment: I did that. Does not work. You may check in the code.

Comment: @AkhilaHegde are you expecting a solution like this https://codesandbox.io/s/kkpn4kkwxv ?

Comment: I am expecting: if I click on Popper(anywhere inside Popper for that matter) I should not trigger `handleClickButton` on the `SimplePopper`. In my case, if I click on anywhere inside the Popper I get the log right? I should avoid that. I checked the your code, it's still not helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things :

In `SimplePopper` component :

```
<div 
     onClick={this.handleClickButton} 
     ref={(node) => { this.parentNode = node }}> //added ref
            <PopperExample>
                <Button>Toggle</Button>
            </PopperExample>
</div>
```

and in `handleClickButton` :

```
handleClickButton = e => {
    if (this.parentNode !== null && this.parentNode !== undefined) {
        this.parentNode.contains(e.target) && console.log('parent Button');
    }
};
```

Function will be executed, if this.parentNode contains the correct target.

and in `PopperExample` :

```
handleButtonPopperClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState(state => ({
        showDiv: true
    }));
};
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kkpn4kkwxv)

Comment: Why are you checking if `preventDefault` & `stopPropagation` are present on the `event`? Aren't they always present?